# Two keywords are overlapping to each other in jsp

Tags: mysql, spring, maven-3

In dashboard 'entries' and 'search' both keywords are overlapping to each other. What is reason behind this?

[image: In dashboard 'entries' and 'search' both keywords are overlapping to each other. What is reason behind this?]

Comment: Can you please give more information? Is there an error message? Can you show some of your JSP code?

Comment: Try it on the Chrome browser. Firefox has some bugs rendering CSS

Comment: No , there is no error message.

Comment: Thanks.It was width issue.